Is there any persistent root method for LineageOS 20?
The gist of it is that I use LineageOS for the Samsung S9 and I use Magisk. Every time the system updates the root is removed, so my question is - does anyone know of any persistent way to get a persistent root?
Apparently AddonSU.zip has been dropped and from my surface research, the answers are very underwhelming. I mean re-adding Magisk is not the end of the world but I really would like it if it were to get stuck around every time the OS updates...
BTW, I would like the long answer of why it happens. I have the vaguest idea that every update overwrites the boot partition or image where Magisk injects itself during boot. But I would like a somewhat in-depth explanation of how Magisk does its thing and why the updates screw it up.

The devices with preinstalled Android 8 have mandatory A/B partition systems which work like MultiROM.
When you update your Android, you install the update in the inactive slot (A or B slot). And after you reboot, you boot into that slot which got rewritten and doesn't have Magisk on it.
That's why each time after you update, you shouldn't let your device reboot so you can open Magisk and flash it to the inactive slot (that you just updated). As simple as that.

What made AddonSU "permanent"?
Is it that back then A/B Partitioning wasn't a thing?
